# Preserve Source Formatting

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Could someone please tell me how I can preserve source formatting for when I paste to my destination workbook? The code below basically transfers data from one spreadsheet to another and then removes duplicate rows in the destination spreadsheet if there is any. Thanks!

```
Sub TransferMar()
'
' Transfer Mar Macro
'

'
    Dim lastRow As Long

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="xxxxxx"

    Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Cells.AutoFilter

    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row


    Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(lastRow, 15)).Copy

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    Dim wkb As Workbook

    Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\Master - Mar.xlsx")

    Columns.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Rows.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Cells.AutoFilter

    erow = wkb.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

    wkb.Sheets(1).Paste Destination:=Sheets(1).Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 15))

    With ActiveSheet
        Set Rng = Range("A3", Range("O3").End(xlDown))
        Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15), Header:=xlYes
    End With


    wkb.ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    wkb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    MsgBox "Rows copied into Master MAR Workbook"

End Sub
```

Comment: `.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats` is the syntax.

Comment: close the source workbook after the paste

Comment: Skip Intro could you add that line of code into my code to make it work? I'm not sure how to incorporate with this line    wkb.Sheets(1).Paste Destination:=Sheets(1).Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 15))

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to paste special is `.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats`.

You could implement this by changing your code to something along the lines of:

```
Worksheets(1).Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 15)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

However, i'm still not sure the above will work because you're closing the workbook containing the copied data before pasting. I'm fairly certain (untested) that your code will work if you close the previous workbook **after** pasting.  The best solution is for your to decide.